# Почему @yield выходит из параграфа если в секции есть ещё один? Blade Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, blade

Вот часть моего кода в файле `research.blade.php`

```
<div class="research__text gap">
    <h1 class="research__title">
        @yield('research__title')
    </h1>
    <p class="research__subtitle">
        @yield('research__subtitle')
    </p>
</div>
```

Вот определение секций в файле `consulting.blade.php`

```
<div class="section__content research__content">
    @section('research__title')
        Get to know how <br>
        <span class="_yellow">we work</span> in one step
    @endsection

    @section('research__subtitle')
        <button class="hover-white">Get a plan</button>
    @endsection

    @include('blocks.research') <!-- импортирование файла research.blade.php -->
</div>
```

Когда так - всё работает и содержимое из секции `research__subtitle` помещается в `p.research__subtitle` корректно. Но стоит мне добавить внутри секции `research__subtitle` тег `p` с любым содержимым - то всё содержимое секции `research__subtitle` помещается не в `p.research__subtitle`, а в его родителя `div.research__text`. Оно будто закрывающий тег из секции воспринимает как закрывающий тег для `p.research__subtitle`. Причём с другими тегами я с таким не встречался. Почему так?

Использую `laravel/framework` версии `9.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то проблема не во framework'е, а в вёрстке. А именно: при попытке в `<p class="research__subtitle"></p>` поместить блочный элемент (а тег `<p>` таковым и является, и тег `<h1>` тоже, и ещё несколько) согласно W3C тег `<p class="research__subtitle"></p>` автоматически закроется в месте, где начнётся другой блочный элемент. В тег `<p>` разрешено встраивать только встроенные (inline'овые) элементы (`<span>`, `<strong>` и другие)